# Proof of Labelling a Line

Tags: geometry

With a finite amount of points on a line, show that the points can be labelled as B1, B2, B3, ..., Bm so that Bj is between Bi and Bk only if j is between i and k.

How can this be done? I am not sure how to interpret the question.

Comment: Ummm, draw some points. I don't see the problem here. Also, define "j is between i and k"

Comment: You'll want to prove this constructively. If you use the real line, what $x$ value could you assign to each $B_i$ to make that come true (hint: don't overthink it :)